# WinJS return in promise array

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a problem with returning array in Winjs promise and I don't have any idea what is wrong with my code. When i create a promise and do .done or .then my promise does nothing.

Code :

```
function getSth(array) {

    return new WinJS.Promise(function () {
        var dbPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + '\\_db.sqlite';

        var i = 0;
        SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath)
              .then(function (db) {
                  console.log('DB opened');
                  return db.eachAsync('SELECT * FROM sthh;', function (row) {
                      array[i++] = row.sth;
                      console.log('Get a ' + row.sth);
                  });
              })
             .then(function (db) {
                 console.log('close the db');
                 db.close();
             }).then(function () {
                 return array;
             });
        return array;
    })
}
```

And in other file I just do something like that :

```
    var array = [];
            var z = getSth(array).then(function () {
                console.log("AAA");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; console.log("#" + array[i]), i++);
            });
```

I will be very gratefull for any suggestion.

Comment: Um, that's not how you create a promise. The function parameter to `new WinJS.Promise` takes three parameters, traditionally named `c`, `e`, and `p`. You call `c(result)` when you have produced a result.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't want to return immediately and instead want to return the array once it is full of elements?

I think you want to write code that is more like this:

```
function getSth(array) {

    var dbPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + '\\_db.sqlite';

    var i = 0;
    return SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath)
          .then(function (db) {
              console.log('DB opened');
              return db.eachAsync('SELECT * FROM sthh;', function (row) {
                  array[i++] = row.sth;
                  console.log('Get a ' + row.sth);
              });
          })
         .then(function (db) {
             console.log('close the db');
             db.close();
         }).then(function () {
             return array;
         });
}
```

Comment: thanks :) That's very obvious sometimes I don't think ;) Thank you!